# How to read text from a file between two given patterns in java8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have one text file. I have to read contents between two given patterns.

for example lets I have a file names - datafromOU.txt

I have to need data from the pattern1 till pattern2.

```
pattern1 : "CREATE EXTR"
Pattern2 :";"
```

But problem is - file has multiple occurances of pattern2. So my requirement is to look for pattern1 and then search immediate occurance of pattern2 after the pattern1. I need to store this into one string and then process later.

Can you help me how to read data from pattern1 and immediate occurance of pattern2 into a string variable using java streams?

I use java8. Thanks a lot in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: You can perhaps use regex (which I assume you already are). Find the lines with the first pattern and then check if it has the second pattern.

Comment: Does Optional count as streams? `Optional.of(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2)).matcher(data)).filter(Matcher::find).map(Matcher::group)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    
    static String getPatternFromString(String startPattern,String endPattern,String data) {
        int startIndex=data.indexOf(startPattern);
        data=data.substring(startIndex);
        int endIndex=data.indexOf(endPattern, startIndex + startPattern.length());
        data=data.substring(0,endIndex+1);
        return data;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\amish\\Desktop\\partie.txt");
        String startPattern="CREATE EXTR";
        String endPattern=";";
        try (BufferedReader leBuffer1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));) {
            StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = leBuffer1.readLine()) != null) {
                everything.append(line);
            }
            String data = everything.toString();
            data = data.trim();
            System.out.println(data);
            System.out.println(getPatternFromString(startPattern,endPattern, data));
            leBuffer1.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still end up reading the entire file to string before searching it? Wouldn't it be better to check the buffer's contents on the fly for the match? Also note that you will need to look for the second pattern "after" the start of the first pattern, and you should take the pattern length into account like this: `endIndex = data.indexOf(endPattern, startIndex + startPattern.length());`